# How To Populate A Gridview With Images Retreieved From Firebase Storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, android-gridview

**I have reviewed other similar posts before posting this, mine is different**
I am current retrieving a list of download urls from my Firestore data base, then trying to download those images from my firebase storage to display them in a gridview.

This is my code so far:

```
final Query chatRoomMsgs = db.collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID).collection("Messages").whereEqualTo("sentby", firebaseAuth.getUid());
    chatRoomMsgs.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    ArrayList<String> sentPicsURLS = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){

                        for(int i = 0; i < queryDocumentSnapshots.size(); i++) {
                            sentPicsURLS.add(documentSnapshot.get("image").toString());

                            if(i == (queryDocumentSnapshots.size()-1)){
                                //now download the images and place them into the proper view
                                for(int z = 0; z < sentPicsURLS.size(); z++){


                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

This is where the images should be pulled and pushed into a gridview:

```
for(int z = 0; z < sentPicsURLS.size(); z++){
         //right here    
}
```

But I am having trouble creating an adapter that can handle this. I have a valid gridview in the activity and I have a layout file that contains an imageview with a ID.

```
final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Chatroom.this, R.layout.chatroom_sent_images,R.id.sent_iv);
    sentPics.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    sentPics.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //empty for now
        }
    });
```

The part I am missing (seems to be) where I actually loop through `sentPicsURLS` and then add them to the adapter... maybe with something like `arrayAdapter.addAll(sentPicsURLS);` inside the `//right here` for loop?

Right now the gridview is showing empty without even the default image view included in `R.layout.chatroom_sent_images`. I feel like I am so close, what am I missing? Thanks!

**Edit**
Here is my chatroom database structure, every chatroom and chatroom message is structured the same way.
[image]

Comment: I amn't sure if i get you correct ,If i did so , You can use observer design pattern (create an interface , implement it in mainactivity , pass it to the adapter) and every time you successfully download an image pass it to the grid , And if you mean that you just want to pass the data , call setAdapter after the for loop

Comment: Do you have more than one image URL in a document? Please add your database schema as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Just added @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, your document hols only a single `image`. So to solve this, there is no need for an extra inner for-loop. To create a list of those images, please use the following lines of code:

```
Query chatRoomMsgs = db.collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID)
    .collection("Messages").whereEqualTo("sentby", firebaseAuth.getUid());
chatRoomMsgs.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            ArrayList<String> sentPicsURLS = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                sentPicsURLS.add(document.getString("image"));
            }
            //Do what you need to do with your list
            Log.d(TAG, "List size: " + sentPicsURLS.size());
        }
    }
});
```

Be also aware that Firebase APIs are asynchronous and you can use that list only inside the callback. Now, the result in your logcat will be size of your list.

Comment: Ok @AlexMamo I have a ArrayList of all the images URLs... how can I pull them and populate a gridview? Assuming I need a custom arrayadapter, but it shouldn't be anything special, literally am looking for an instagram-like 3-wide gridview... so I created a layout with just one grid view in it, but I don't know how to actually get/download those images from my firebase storage...new question maybe?

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work. Now that you have a list full of images, you just simply need to create an adapter and pass that list to a constructor. You should really make your own attempt given the information in this comment and if you have hard time implementing that, add a new question so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: Please also note that your images are simply names` longId/number.jpg`. In order to get images from Firebase Storage, you need URLs. Those are not URLs.

Comment: will do... I was assuming I could just pass those half-URLs into some sort of constructor and add whatever precedes them programatically, then fetch the image and push it into the array adapter. No?

Comment: Oh yes, you can construct the link on the client. It will work perfectly fine.

Comment: figured I could as the link to the should just be `firebaseappurl` + `sentPicsURLS.get(i)`

Comment: Yes, that correct. You should only add the part with `https://...`.

Comment: do you know off hand what to call to download those images to the imageview? Do I need an external library like picasso or do they have a function built in like `download()` or something

Comment: To get the download URL when you upload a picture check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660) out. And [Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581858/how-to-avoid-downloading-image-from-firebase-if-i-have-already-downloaded-previo) will help you solve the other issue.

Comment: got it... I'm starting to wonder if 'download' the actually the right terminology because I don't want to download and permanently store the image onto the users device time and time again...they should only have/need to see the image when they are in the app

Comment: Glide provides a cache so you are not going to download an image over and over again.

Comment: perfect, I'll read their documentation but I assume there's some sort of method I could call that would handle the removal of specific images from the grid view no

Comment: have another for you... just cant wrap my mind around this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840789/how-to-load-and-add-images-to-an-android-arrayadapter-using-glide