# How to load and add images to an android arrayadapter using Glide

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-glide, android-gridview

I am trying to load an image using the Glide repository, then ultimately add that image into a gridview. I am currently trying to do this by creating a blank imageview, loading the image, adding the image to the imageview and then adding the imageview to my array adapter. The layout I am using with the arrayadapter contains a single imageview. Here is my code, layout, and error I am getting when I try to load the images

```
final Query chatRoomMsgs = db.collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID).collection("Messages").whereEqualTo("sentby", UID);
    chatRoomMsgs.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    //ArrayList<ImageView> sentPicsURLS = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){

                        for(int i = 0; i < queryDocumentSnapshots.size(); i++) {

                             //sentPicsURLS.add(documentSnapshot.getString("image"));
                            ImageView tempimage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                            Glide.with(Chatroom.this).load("gs://testapp-72419.appspot.com" + documentSnapshot.getString("image")).into(tempimage);
                            arrayAdapter.add(tempimage);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                        //Do what you need with your list


                    }
                }
            });
```

My arrayadapter:

```
final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Chatroom.this, R.layout.chatroom_sent_images,R.id.sent_iv);
    sentPics.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

chatroom_sent_images layout file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B84CD5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sent_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then the strange error I am getting when the app tries to load the images:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

I'm not sure there's a single `testView` mentioned anywhere? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for that inner for-loop. Besides that, `gs://testapp-72419.appspot.com` is not the correct path. You should use something like "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..." Please note that it should also contain a token at the end.

Comment: @AlexMamo I see, so should be calling `getDownLoadURL()` for each of the images and passing THOSE into Glide... that way they exact link with token is automatically built into it

Comment: No, you get the token once you upload the image.